# Why does switch only show default output in console and *not* in the actual application?

Tags: java, switch-statement, default

I'm making my first java desktop application (which explains the lack of knowledge), when I run the project, the default output comes in the console instead of the actual project, wheras when the field is filled in correctly, it shows the output on the application/project.

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    String name = textBoxName.getText();
    switch (textBoxName.getText()) {
        case "":
            System.out.println("Name field cannot be blank!");
            break;
        default:
            Message.setText(name);         
    }
}
```

Comment: The console is where `System.out` and `System.err` go. Where are you expecting to see the output of println?

Comment: in the application front-end :'(

Comment: Text can't just randomly appear in a Swing application. You need to create a UI component and explicitly set the text it contains.

Comment: Shouldn’t your switch be `switch (name) {` ?

Answer (score 0):

Using `System.out.println("your message here");` you are writing in the console, which is usually used to debug things. If you want to show the message to the user in a GUI interface, there is an useful class in Swing.
Instead of `System.out.println();` try

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Name field cannot be blank!");
```

which will create a dialog with your message inside it and a button to close it. You can also specify a title of the dialog and the type of dialog like this:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Name field cannot be blank!", "Title of the message", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
```

where instead of `JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE` you can also put `ERROR_MESSAGE`, `INFORMATION_MESSAGE`, `WARNING_MESSAGE` or `QUESTION_MESSAGE`.